# Unable to use custom font in iText7 Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itext7

I'm creating an application on Visual Studio and have added in a function that creates a PDF on button click event using iText7. I'm using a custom font that is in my resources and it works fine using the path "../../Resources.[FontName].ttf" when debugging through visual studio but when I run the application file I get an error saying that `the resource or file cannot be found`. I assume it is because the file is stored in the .resx file and isn’t accessible through the path (shown above) outside of visual studio. What path can I use to access the font file so that it works outside of visual studio through the delivered application?

Comment: is any update? Please check if my answer can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I would share the solution I used for my own problem in case anyone stumbles over the same issue.

It is rather simple. I added the font .ttf file into my resources. It must be stored as a byte[] file. So go to your Resources.Designer.cs file and make sure it looks something like this:

```
internal static byte[] BebasNeueRegular {
        get {
            object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("BebasNeueRegular", resourceCulture);
            return ((byte[])(obj));
        }
    }
```

Then in your class where you are creating the PDF, set your font using iText's `PdfFontFactory`:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(Properties.Resources.BebasNeueRegular, true);
doc.SetFont(font);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PdfFontFactory.CreateFont` method to load the font file.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("E:\\AmaticSC-Regular.ttf");
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("E:\\demo.pdf");
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);
    Paragraph header = new Paragraph("HEADER").SetFont(font).SetFontSize(50);

    document.Add(header);
    document.Close();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I still don't think this would work on a client PC that doesn't have the font file on their PC.